# Binary to Decimal 32bit signed with PHP

Tags: php, binary, decimal, 32-bit

I currently have a Decimal that is coming through as: 4294960896

This is then converted to Binary with this function:

```
decbin('4294960896')
```

Which equals: 11111111111111111110011100000000

I then need to take that binary and convert it to the 32bit signed version which should be '-6400'

I can't seem to find any built in functions that support 32bit signed output.

Comment: `4294960896-pow(2,32)` ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hexadecimal representation of the number 4294960896 is FFFFE700h. This should be interpreted as 32 bit signed long.
The functions that support such tasks are [pack](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) and [unpack](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php).

```
$i64 = 4294960896;

$i32 = unpack('l',pack('V',$i64))[1];
//int(-6400)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used

> ```
> $i64 = unpack('L',pack('l',$decimal))[1];
> $t = base_convert($i64,10,2);
> $r = str_pad($t,32,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
> ```

It seemed more logical to use `L` and `l` formats for (un)packing, to keep it machine independent. Wrote a lot of tests though, to be sure it works.